# Load balancing/routing between replicas

Tags: docker, docker-compose, routes, load-balancing, replication

I have the following docker setup:

```
Web --> traefik --> frontend/api --> backend
```

I have a `docker-compose.yml` that configures frontend/api and backend. The frontend has an HTTP connection to the backend, by calling it with its container name `http://backend:8080/`.

Now I want to scale the frontend and backend in parallel (2 frontends and 2 backends).

So I start it with:

```
docker-compose up -d --scale frontend=2 --scale backend=2
```

The traefik does the load balancing for the frontend. But now I can't use container names to route from the frontend to the backend anymore.

How can I organize the routing between scaled containers with pure docker and docker-compose? *(No swarm or kubernetes.)*

**Note:**
A solution to scale only the backend but access all replicas round-robin under the same hostname from the frontend might be half of a solution already.